# How to create trees with Qtree and math symbols

Tags: trees, qtree

Hi  I am trying to create a tree with two branches R<1 , R>1, which are labeled by math symbols (indices, \leq, ...). The second branch must be developed further. This almost works

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}\usepackage{float}\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{tikz,qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.0 R_*$\leq$1  R_*>1 i_M$\leq$h_*
       ]
\end{document}
```

but actually I want the last branch `i_M$\leq$h`  to be a child of R_*>1. I tried to group them

```
\Tree [.0 R_*$\leq$1  [.R_*>1 i_M$\leq$h_*]
   ]
```

but this ends  up in fatal error .  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
\Tree [.0 {$R_*\leq 1$} [.{$R_*>1$} {$i_M\leq h_*$} ]  ]
\end{document}
```